# Подскажите как организовать проверку является ли строка пустой

Tags: java

Пытался организовать проверку на пустую строчку и если она пустая вернуться к вводу строки. Пробовал через через (do while) не получается

```
int StringCount = 0; 
String[] stringArray; 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
stringArray = new String[StringCount]; 
for (int i=0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    //do {  
System.out.println("Введте слово(а) в строку " + (i + 1));
   //while (stringArray[i].trim().length() == 0) {
stringArray[i]=in.next(); 
}
//} while (stringArray[i].trim().length()< 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Лучше проверять так:

```
if ("".equals(s)) {
```

Оно работает даже если в переменной `s` окажется null.

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не воспользоваться [String.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)?